# Get number of retweet of any URL with new Twitter API 1.1

Tags: twitter

I have a question about new twitter API 1.1

Now I use: http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=SOME_URL_HERE
and I get number of retweet of any URL.

Which is the new function in API 1.1 to get number of retweet of any URL?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the same... the new API seems horrendously complicated by comparison. :/

Comment: There isn't a Twitter API endpoint that does that.